# How can I add a service config file to my asp.net MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

We are an ISV building a small web application that can be deployed either on-premise or in Azure. Up until now we had been using a `web.config` file to configure our app.
Now that we started pushing some of it in Azure, we would like to be able to tweak some of those `appSettings` in Azure.

Our understanding is that we need to use a *service configuration file* instead. Looking around, a lot of places explain how to do that using an azure deploy project. We currently are using a simple ASP.NET MVC project and using a **downloaded publish profile** from our Azure website (using the free Azure websites thing for now).

**Is there a way to publish a *service configuration file* as part of the MVC project?** or do we have to have a web-deploy project?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just stick with Azure Websites in your situation. Settings configured on the Configuration tab inside Azure Websites take priority over settings in the `web.config`. You can override settings inside both `<appSettings>` and `<connectionStrings>` elements.

(To answer the second part of your question, you can't deploy a `.cscfg` file without creating a full Web Role).

Comment: Cool, thanks. I just wished it extracted existing appSettings for you. But this will do. I just hope it survives re-deploy.